# is it possible to make nginx using cer format with the certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am using acme to auto renew the certificate of domain, the `acme.sh` generated certificate format is `cer` format like this: `/root/.acme.sh/ttt208.com_ecc/ca.cer`. The nginx using pem format, is it possible to make nginx using the `cer` format? this is the cer file:

```
[root@ops001 ttt208.com_ecc]# cat fullchain.cer
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIETzCCAzegAwIBAgISBEDHABxB8KoNuolJmVul04xfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD
EwJSMzAeFw0yijA1MjMxMjM5MjlaFw0yMjA4MjExMjM5MjhaMBUxEzARBgNVBAMT
CnR0dDIwOC5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAROYFkF6OQtEtKc
gVRSwl4Qtj1TBUBT22bVksHqX09pUWAl1zdlzix5cFRYYMlfdXcbLTfVSLcki4y2
fbqxy+t5o4ICRTCCAkEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgeAMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUF
BwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQla2XHk7Q39sKz
6G4CwmxgIhcszzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQULrMXt1hWy65QCUDmH6+dixTCxjBVBggr
BgEFBQcBAQRJMEcwIQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFWh0dHA6Ly9yMy5vLmxlbmNyLm9yZzAi
BggrBgEFBQcwAoYWaHR0cDovL3IzLmkubGVuY3Iub3JnLzAVBgNVHREEDjAMggp0
dHQyMDguY29tMEwGA1UdIARFMEMwCAYGZ4EMAQIBMDcGCysGAQQBgt8TAQEBMCgw
JgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly9jcHMubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnMIIBBAYKKwYB
BAHWeQIEAgSB9QSB8gDwAHYAKXm+8J45OSHwVnOfY6V35b5XfZxgCvj5TV0mXCVd
x4QAAAGA8STpWgAABAMARzBFAiEA5sD33j9CMR0mI6mhWyJNJeXkTW3jV3ScIYHq
ctyrCGoCIAlVaZz5cB3jkNQFK0a9GuPfKPRY8VzPCT2aMWzFXCgnAHYAb1N2rDHw
MRnYmQCkURX/dxUcEdkCwQApBo2yCJo32RMAAAGA8STpkQAABAMARzBFAiEAvydT
bit82mOhg390IPwGrrIM7TaVuaK/ibvtEpdQoXYCIG461oxYEXkiy/T85StWYk0y
zHV9+9jDga7AsqEAE296MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQABqfMN53zdbCQTolLu
mExCTe21P6ngqJiy6fMoBUsrxvGg1bmSjgV7UicjSrI/qErmUUDx9PGD+equIdc6
vLnqorf2gnyjtruSQBCf0BFjG59uN69i7w4LECNLmiv8ZNLpBVsJAXObgUPf9Cws
fsjGkZVEr84kCvkzTiLr2/ARMW0OFz3/PZefLCimwue0nydQLM7oeS+Yv7KHy6ps
OBRIf5Y708dig3SQf5Kck/EZDQO04gNeSg7CFV+pMJfPSH+vd6oz/l5umH9MwfYd
jEKsAFFe1K/k+bIJde5/5c+m2s85WxHUJil5SKSvRHuko6NNAnIeYa19xFbpmvHc
zSXJ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

After generating the new `cer` file you can run command like:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

([source](https://serverfault.com/a/254630/293588))

Comment: I have already tried this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1101593/unable-to-load-certificate-when-convert-cer-to-pem @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Dolphin, and is it work for you? Some errors you get?

Comment: it not works for me. the error is: `unable to load certificate
140129921161104:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1220:
140129921161104:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:386:Type=X509` @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Dolphin, can you please provide in your question the first few lines from `cer` file?

Comment: @Dolphin, and do you give permission to `nginx` user to read the `pem` file?

Comment: I have add the cer format generate by acme.sh.@Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Dolphin, check if `nginx` have the permission to read the resulting `pem` file

Comment: this error is not the nginx output, this error was happend when convert the cer to pem, it could not convert pem success. I did not using the file because could not convert cer to pem. the nginx need pem foramt.@Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Dolphin, `dem` file looks fine for me. Have no idea from where you get the error